# How to display custom Form Drop down list label?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can't figure out how to edit the label output by cakephp 2.0 in a form.

I have a simple drop down list with 3 items and all i want to do is change the text thats outputed (which of course prints the fieldname) how on earth  do i do it. Ive looked a the 1.3 and 2.0 docs and i couldnt figure it out;

```
echo $this->Form->input('accounttype', array('options'=>array('customer' => 'Customer', 'retailer' => 'Retailer','manufacturer'=>'Manufacturer')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the label property to achieve this:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'accounttype', 
    array(
        'label' => 'Foo', 
        'options'=>array(
            'customer' => 'Customer', 
            'retailer' => 'Retailer',
            'manufacturer'=>'Manufacturer'
        )
    )
);
```

See also:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: thanks alot you made that look easy, spend a good hour trying to do that:)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `label` property:

```
echo $this->Form->input('accounttype', array('label' => 'Account Type'));
```